# Is the word Keen, meaning wail, related to a Hebrew word referring to mourning?

Tags: etymology

I often come across words that are the same or similar between English and other languages. In this case, I'm curious about the word "keen", meaning to wail, and the Hebrew word "kinah" (plural "kinot") which refers to prayers said in mourning.  Are the two related?

Information about *how* you found the answer would be appreciated so I can use similar methods in the future.

Comment: I had the following answer ready to send when this was closed. I post it here instead.

Comment: The OED gives the following etymologies for *keen* v.:

Comment: > *keen* v. [f. Ir. *caoin*- , stem of *caoin-im* 'I wail': see *keen* sb.]

Comment: and for the substantive *keen*:

Comment: > *keen* sb. [a. Ir. *caoine* /kinə/, f. *caoinim* (OIr. *cáinim*, *cóinim*) 'I weep, wail, lament'; cf. *keen* v.]

Comment: So, as you can see, English keen is not related to Hebrew, but rather Irish. This is rather more likely, seeing as very few people spoke Hebrew in the British Isles, but lots of people spoke Irish.

Comment: How is it even *related* to 'What are your favorite English language tools?' Any doubts should be set at rest with Barrie England's answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler, question has re-opened, so no need now for multiple comments.

Comment: @JohnLawler You may want to (I wish you would) post an answer now that the question 'has re-opened.'

Comment: @jwpat7 I didn't know questions 're-open'.

Comment: "... how you found the answer" to the kind of (example) question in the first para, is what I believe the OP is asking. Not "Are the two related?"

Answer (score 1):

You need a dictionary that gives etymologies. The most comprehensive is the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/), but it requires a paid subscription. You may find the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/) of some help.

Comment: Why the down vote? If it was because the question was closed, look: it's open now.

Comment: @Kris. Perhaps it was because I only answered the final paragraph of the question.

Comment: I thought (think) the closing sentence **is** the question. The "Are the two related?" is part of the theme, not the question. So your answer is complete.

Comment: @Kris. I think I was rather looking at it as General Reference, but thought I'd give some pointers, rather than just vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=keen):

> "lament," 1811, from Ir. caoinim "I weep, wail, lament," **from O.Ir. coinim** "I wail." Related: Keened; keening. As a noun from 1830.

[ODO's entry for keen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/keen--2) reads as follows:

> v. wail in grief for a dead person:
>   n. an Irish funeral song accompanied by wailing in lamentation for the dead.

So, no, the English *keen* does not appear to have any connection to the Hebrew *kinnot*. Considering that the Hebrew word probably [dates back to the 6th century CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnot), it's unlikely that it has any connection with English either.

[Personally, I was under the mistaken impression that *keening* was onomatopoeic in origin.]

Comment: See my comment @OP